# How to Just show \subsubsection numbers

Tags: numbering

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}
\section*{Section1}

\subsection*{subsection1}
\subsubsection{Another layer of subsection}

\end{document}
```

I just want to show the subsubsection numbering, without the trailing section and subsection numbers in the front.
In the output it appears as 0.0.1, I want it to appear as 1

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

chngcntr will also disable the resetting of the number of your `\subsubsection` in a new subsection. As long as you using only the starred version of `\subsection` this doesn't matter. In other cases you probably should better redefine `\thesubsubsection` to change the representation of the counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
%\counterwithout{subsubsection}{subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\begin{document}
\section{Section1}

\subsection{subsection1}
\subsubsection{Another layer of subsection}

\subsection{subsection1}
\subsubsection{Another layer of subsection}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) package to remove the relationship between two counters.

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{subsubsection}{subsection}
```